# Arch Linux installation keyboard layout de-latin1 in /etc/vconsole.conf

Tags: keyboard, archlinux

I am installing Arch Linux and the official installation guide tell to set keyboard layout as

```
KEYMAP=de-latin1
```

I searched and this is Germany keyboard layout which is different from QWERTY. Also there was no US keyboard layout available. What should I put in KEYMAP for english us keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all available layouts via `localectl list-keymaps`. If you wish to have a standard QWERTY layout, you might want to use `KEYMAP=us`

Have a look at [this Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration) for more information.